# AWS Copy data from one database to another

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-data-pipeline

We (on the company I work) have a production database (MySQL) and we want to create a new database (PostgreSQL) for BI/Analytics.

The whole infrastructure is on AWS, and we have to copy the data from the production to the analytics database, I thought to use AWS Glue, but it didn't copy the real data, instead it just gets (nor even creates) the production database table schema.
Then I found out data pipeline (also in AWS), but I have no idea if this is what I have to use or if I messed up the crawler configuration on the AWS Glue.

Which of these two products should I use to accomplish this task and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Amazon Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) (AWS DMS) can migrate and continuously replicate data from one database to another. I believe it is more suited to this purpose than either of the services you have listed in your question.